# linking static libraries in iOS5

Tags: ios5

I am new to iOS 5.
Currently working with xcode 4.2,Base sdk iOS 5.0,Apple LLVM compiler 3.0,architechture armv7.
Whenever I try to link a static library the following warning comes up.

ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/shilpasurendran/Desktop/InputVal_aslib/InputVal_aslib/iCodeBlogsMathLibrary/libICodeMathUtils.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

I even tried changing deployment targets and compiler,but of no use.
Please help.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to build for armv7 architecture which means you want to build for a real device not the simulator.

The library you are linking to is in i386 architecture meaning it is compiled for the simulator.

When using a third-party library there often is a structure like this:

```
Library
  build
    Release-iphoneos
    Release-iphonesimulator
    Release-universal
```

If there is a universal build you should use that one. Try using the one under Release-iphoneos otherwise.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thnku so much.It really helped me.